# Pass Dict to Array python

Tags: dictionary

I'm working on a small project in which I get cryptocurrency data from a website using python API. When I do this the type of object that is returned is a type "dict" and looks as in the following link.

https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/gdax/btcusd/ohlc

Now I would like to pass the values into an array object so that i can make calculations with them, plot etc.

Could anybody please point me in the right direction how i can do this?

currently im passing it into a CSV which seems less efficient to me.

```
    my_data = client.get_markets(data=data)

    my_data = str(my_data)


    # resultFyle = open(f"        
    {curr}_{exch}_{start_date}_{to_date}.csv",'w+',newline='')
    # wr = csv.writer(resultFyle)

    test_string = ''
    test_string_1 = ''

    for char in my_data:
           if char == '[':
    #          wr.writerow([test_string])
              print(test_string)
              test_string = ''
           elif char == ']':
               char = ''
           else:
               test_string = test_string + char
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in python have a number of methods for consuming data from other data structures.
there is `array.extend()` and `array.fromlist()`.

From what I see in the data, API response is a dict, but that dict is only a collection of lists, each of which is a different candle time period. Then the OHLC data points are also lists, and NumPy's arrays do not support nesting.
You could convert one (or each) of those candle sets into four lists: one for Open, one for Close, one for High and one for Low. Each element of those lists would correspond to the other lists at the same index. Then you would convert to array (if you really need to)

```
import array as array_module
my_data = client.get_markets(data=data)
open = []
close = []
high = []
low = []
for candle in my_data["result"]["60"]:
    open.append(candle[1])
    high.append(candle[2])
    low.append(candle[3])
    close.append(candle[4])
sixty_minutes_open_array = array_module.array("f", open)
sixty_minutes_high_array = array_module.array("f", high)
sixty_minutes_low_array = array_module.array("f", low)
sixty_minutes_close_array = array_module.array("f", close)
```

But you can also make calculations on values from a dictionary in python,
or you can stop after creating separate lists and before creating the arrays and do calculations on your lists.